# Obtaining HIT Status while Creating HIT using Mturkr Package in R

Tags: r, mechanicalturk

```
    library("MTurkR")
    credentials(c("EXAMPLEAWSKEY","EXAMPLEAWSSCERETKEY"))
    AccountBalance()
    #Fetching AccountBalance=$0.00

    # First set qualifications
    # ListQualificationTypes() to see different qual types
    qualReqs = paste(

        # Set Location to US only
        GenerateQualificationRequirement(
            "Location","==","US"),

        sep="" )

    # Create new batch of hits:
    newHIT = CreateHIT(

        # layoutid in sandbox:
        hitlayoutid="EXAMPLEHITLAYOUTID",
        sandbox=T,
        annotation = "HET Experiment with Pre-Screen",
        assignments = "1200",
        title="Rate this hypothetical representative",
        description="It's easy, just rate this
            hypothetical representative on how well
            she delivers funds to his district",
        reward=".50",
        duration=seconds(hours=4),
        expiration=seconds(days=7),
        keywords="survey, question, answers, research,
                politics, opinion",
        auto.approval.delay=seconds(days=15),
        qual.reqs=qualReqs
    )

    # Get HITId (record result below)
    newHIT$HITId

    HITStatus(hit="EXAMPLEHITID")
    #not able to fetch HIT STATUS.
    #I Can see HIT been Created in Worker Sandbox, But after submitting the   by the worker I am not able to fetch anything. 

review = GetAssignments(hit="Example HITID",
    status="Submitted", return.all=T)
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error (AWS.MechanicalTurk.HITDoesNotExist): Hit 3IV1AEQ4DRV9ICWQ5F0YS4QBNVOJ85 does not exist. (1444808078544)
>
> # Error in while (request$total > runningtotal) { : 
>    # missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is pretty simple, actually, despite the not terribly informative (second) error message. You've created a HIT in the sandbox but you're trying to check its status on the live server, where it does not exist.

You can solve this by passing a `sandbox = TRUE` (or `sandbox = FALSE`) argument to each function and do so consistently across all of your code. An easier alternative is to specify a global option:

`options(MTurkR.sandbox = TRUE)`

at the beginning of your code, which you can then easily toggle on and off as needed.